# Enumerate possible states transition of Workflow Foundation state machine

Tags: workflow-foundation, enumeration, transition

For GUI purposes I need by current state of state machine to enumerate possible available states of transition. For example there is transitions: A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D. Assuming state machine is in A state, so I need get list of B and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my own answer, right now it looks as stupid question.
So, it is enough to create lightweight object StateMachineWorkflowInstance around my instance of Workflow, here the code:

```
StateMachineWorkflowInstance smw =
            new StateMachineWorkflowInstance(MyWorkflowRuntime, A);
return smw.PossibleStateTransitions.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.0, the `WorkflowApplication.Idle` event contains `WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs`, which contains a `Bookmarks` property.